# search dont work well (use storyBoard, coreData)

Tags: ios, search, core-data, storyboard, uisearchbar

I add search bar follow tutorial but in some reason the search dont show me results.

note: I add "self tableView" in line 2 to avoid error.
maybe this is the problem? or the problem with the IF?

**git: https://github.com/dennis87/git_bookList**

I think the problem is in this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //cell create
    if (nil == cell)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show search results");
        Books *book = [[self searchResults]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[cell textLabel]setText:[book title]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Configuring cell to show normal data");
        Books *book = [[self fetchResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[cell textLabel]setText:[book title]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I tried put NSlogs and get that this NSLog never printed, so maybe the problems is with the IF?
what I do wrong?

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSLog(@"Previous Search Results were removed.");
    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    for (Books *book in [self.fetchResultsController fetchedObjects])
    {
        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [book.title isEqualToString:scope])
        {
            NSLog(@"entered");
            NSComparisonResult result = [book.title compare:searchText
                                                   options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                NSLog(@"Adding book.title '%@' to searchResults as it begins with search text '%@'", book.title, searchText);
                [self.searchResults addObject:book];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. `self.searchDisplayController` is `nil` because you haven't set that outlet in the Storyboard. Ctrl-drag from "Books Table View Controller" to "Search Display Controller" and select the "searchDisplayController" outlet.
2. Your `filterContentForSearchText` method checks the value of `scope`, but that is `nil` because you have not defined any scopes in the seach bar.
3. `numberOfSectionsInTableView` should return `1` for the search results table view.

If you fix these issues, you should be able to see some search results.

**REMARK:** This line

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

seems suspicious to me. You ask `self.tableView` to dequeue a cell even for the search results table view. I have seen this somewhere on SO as a method to use prototype cells with a search display, and it may be correct, but I have a small doubt.

*If it is correct*, then you don't need the following `if (nil == cell) { ... }`, because that method always returns a cell from the prototype.

You should also note that inside the  `if (nil == cell) { ... }` block you assign the value to a local variable `cell` instead of the variable from the outer scope.

Comment: thanks for help. 

what you mean by define scope how to define it? can u explain or link tutorial that explain it?

Comment: @Dennis: The [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848) sample project should be a good starting point. You can define the search scopes in the Storyboard file, in the properties of the Search Bar. - But scopes are **optional**. You can just remove the check `if ([scope isEqualToString:@"All"] || [book.title isEqualToString:scope])` in your code.

Comment: the problem solved, thank you.. I just delete that line :)
I want understand better what happens..
why the guy from the tutorials used this IF? what that mean @"All".
the scope is default?

Comment: @Dennis: In the TableSearch sample project, there are scopes defined, and the first one is "All". - But there is no default scope.